# The On Success Listener for query.get() won't execute properly. The code returns an error saying that the load has not been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel

So, my roommate and I are trying to develop an app to help students living on campus at our school keep track of their laundry.  However, we are having trouble creating new laundry loads.

Our addLoad function is supposed to add a `LaundryHolder` object to Firebase (containing the machine number, whether it is a washer or dryer, who owns the load, and how many seconds are left for the load), whereas the `LaundryLoad` object contains a LaundryHolder, observer function (`notifyDataSetChanged()` for the `LaundryLoadFragment)`, and timer (with time form `LaundryHolder`).

In Firebase, each clothingItem has a load ID with which to identify which load it is in on the user side.  For our implementation to work, we need to fetch the ID which Firebase gives our `LaundryHolder`, which is why we are adding an `onSuccessListener` to a temporary query.  The issue arises, however, when the query doesn't succeed or fail, and we can't figure out what is going on here.

This is the error we get:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.rosehulman.roselaundrytracker, PID: 11847
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property load has not been initialized
at edu.rosehulman.roselaundrytracker.model.LaundryLoadViewModel.addLoad(LaundryLoadViewModel.kt:42)
at edu.rosehulman.roselaundrytracker.adapter.AddLoadAdapter.addLoad(AddLoadAdapter.kt:67)
at edu.rosehulman.roselaundrytracker.fragment.AddLoadFragment.onCreateView$lambda-1(AddLoadFragment.kt:32)
at edu.rosehulman.roselaundrytracker.fragment.AddLoadFragment.$r8$lambda$lIyFvxsLH_bCt-kHzadMjy2Ls_Y(Unknown Source:0)
at edu.rosehulman.roselaundrytracker.fragment.AddLoadFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Does anyone have any idea?

```
class LaundryLoadViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var loads = ArrayList<LaundryLoad>()
    private var curPos = 0
    lateinit var ref: CollectionReference
    lateinit var uid: String
    private var onlyOwned = true
    private val subscriptions = HashMap<String, ListenerRegistration>()
    fun getPreference() = onlyOwned
    fun addLoad(machineNumber: Int, machineType: String, contents: ArrayList<ClothingItem>, time: Long, observer: () -> Unit){
        val holder = LaundryHolder(machineNumber, machineType.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()) == "dryer", time * LaundryLoadFragment.SEC_TO_MIN, uid)
//        val load = LaundryLoad(holder, observer)
//        loads.add(load)
        ref.add(holder)
        lateinit var load: LaundryLoad
        val query = ref
            .whereEqualTo("machineNumber",machineNumber)
            .whereEqualTo("owner",uid)
        query.get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
            snapshot.documents.forEach {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Retrieving load from Firebase")
                load = LaundryLoad.from(it, observer)
            }
        }
        query.get().addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Retrieval failed due to $it")
            }
//        val query = ref.whereEqualTo("machineNumber",machineNumber).whereEqualTo("dryer",machineType.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())=="dryer")
        load.addMany(contents)
        loads.add(load)
    }

    fun addListener(fragmentName: String, observer: () -> Unit) {
        lateinit var subscription: ListenerRegistration
        loads.clear()
        val auth = Firebase.auth
        val user = auth.currentUser!!
        val clothes = ArrayList<ClothingItem>()
        uid = user.uid
        ref = Firebase.firestore.collection(LaundryLoad.COLLECTION_PATH)
        val ref2 = Firebase.firestore.collection(ClothingItem.COLLECTION_PATH)
        val inLoadQuery = ref2.whereNotEqualTo("load","")
        inLoadQuery.addSnapshotListener { snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
            error?.let {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: $it")
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            snapshot?.documents?.forEach {
                clothes.add(ClothingItem.from(it))
            }
        }
        if(onlyOwned) {
            val query = ref.whereEqualTo("owner",uid)
            subscription = query
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
                    error?.let {
                        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: $it")
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                    }
                    retrieveLoads(snapshot, clothes, observer)
                }
        } else {
            subscription = ref
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
                    error?.let {
                        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: $it")
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                    }
                    retrieveLoads(snapshot, clothes, observer)
                }
        }
        subscriptions[fragmentName] = subscription
        observer()
    }

    private fun retrieveLoads(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?, clothes: ArrayList<ClothingItem>, observer: () -> Unit) {
        snapshot?.documents?.forEach {
            loads.add(LaundryLoad.from(it, observer))
        }
        for (load in loads) {
            for (item in clothes) {
                if (item.load == load.getId()) {
                    load.addToLoad(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun removeListener(fragmentName: String) {
        for(load in loads) {
            ref.document(load.getId()).set(load.laundryHolder)
        }
        subscriptions[fragmentName]?.remove()
        subscriptions.remove(fragmentName)
    }

    fun togglePreference() {
        onlyOwned = !onlyOwned
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace that you're getting?

Comment: Ok, the edit has been made

Comment: I recommend searching for any error message you get, as this has been covered in quite a few places: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+lateinit+property+load+has+not+been+initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ref` has not been initialized when you `ref.add(holder)` in `addLoad`. It's impossible for us to say why that is, as the code that calls `addLoad` seems to be missing, but the stack trace should point you pretty directly to where the problem is.